# Adding content to div like the weather or my email or twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Sorry to ask but I have searched but coming up with nothing.

I have some divs ( I know everyone has a 'div' ) and I want to add feeds\content

See my code below, in these 'widgets' can I add things like twitter and my email and a news feed?

also not  to be too picky, can I just get text only ?

How do I go about it ? Is their something

here is the html, jquery and css code...

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>snap to grid</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="nothing yet">
  <meta name="author" content="Pavle Stojanovic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="snap.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    $(function() {
      $( ".widgets" ).draggable({ grid: [ 10, 10 ] });
        $( ".widgets" ).draggable({
            containment: "#draggable-container",
            drag: function(event){
                if($('.widgets').position().left + $('.widgets').width() == $('.body-container').width()){
                   event.preventDefault();  //cancel the drag.
                    console.log('d');
                }
            }
        });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body-container">
    <div id="draggable-container">
        <div id="widget-1" class="widgets"><p>Twitter</p></div>
        <div id="widget-2" class="widgets"><p>Weather</p></div>
        <div id="widget-3" class="widgets"><p>News</p></div>
        <div id="widget-4" class="widgets"><p>Email</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



html, body{
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#widget-1{
    background-color: blue;
}

#widget-2{
    background-color: purple;
}

#widget-3{
    background-color: orange;
}

#widget-4{
    background-color: green;
}

.widgets{
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}

#draggable-container{
    position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question please?

Comment: In my oblong shape div I would like to see current emails ( say my Gmail ) or another to show the local weather ?

Comment: I dont think Gmail would allow that but not really sure. About twitter, you should go and see developer guide. There are ways to receive and implement feeds to your website. https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: RSS feed :) I think that's what I might need